# What is this construct with flow-control-keyword-like identifiers?

Tags: c++

The following code is [from Chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/43.0.2357.132/sandbox/linux/seccomp-bpf-helpers/syscall_parameters_restrictions.cc):

```
  return Switch(cmd)
      .CASES((F_GETFL,
              F_GETFD,
              F_SETFD,
              F_SETLK,
              F_SETLKW,
              F_GETLK,
              F_DUPFD,
              F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC),
             Allow())
      .Case(F_SETFL,
            If((long_arg & ~kAllowedMask) == 0, Allow()).Else(CrashSIGSYS()))
      .Default(CrashSIGSYS());
```

Presumably some sort of class/template construct has been used to produce what looks like flow control constructs, but as an expression rather than statements. Is this idiomatic in modern C++? Does it have a name?

Comment: Tbh, I feel like google does and promotes a lot of strange stuff that I personally would not consider good C++ / advice.

Comment: There's something similar that Bjarne worked on that actually enables pattern matching, but I don't know if this has any extra functionality like that.

Comment: Coming from a C background, I personally find it utterly hideous and anti-idiomatic. But I was wondering if this is something C++ people like, or some crazy Google thing that's also foreign and anti-idiomatic to C++ people. :-)

Comment: It's not really a C vs. C++ thing... you'll find Design by Contract frameworks/libraries for C too, where there's analogous lines to check return values, preconditions, invariants etc...  It's unusual to see them actually used.

Answer (score 2):

It's not idiomatic.  It's a type of *assertion* and return-value check.  Some people/docs refer to such requirements as *return value constraints*, others consider them part of the function *post-conditions* - particularly those from a *Design by Contract* perspective.

(It's checking that `cmd` is one of the allowed values - with `F_SETFL` also needing `(long_arg & ~kAllowedMask)` tp be `0`, otherwise ensuring it issues `SIGSYS` instead of continuing to return an un-allowed value.)

(Hadn't looked at who'd posted the question - am sure you know all the above R, expect perhaps the *"constraints"* term - not widely used in C++ circles)

Comment: I understand what it's doing, but the same could be done with actual `switch` statement, `if`, etc. What's the reason for using this crazy construct with `Switch`, `CASES`, `Case`, etc. chained by `.` operator?

Comment: @R.. I haven't looked at the implementation, but one way it may differ is being easily optionally disabled when the performance cost proves unacceptable.  Another is that a `switch` only works for certain types, while this `Switch` class may support any comparable objects.  It also creates a single point of maintenance for the expression being returned... direct use of `if` of `switch` to test the condition, then a separate `return` statement, risks someone returning something other than what they validated (perhaps subtly: side effects from the expression).